# Some Inventory modules are missing when magento upgrade from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.5p1, composer-install

I upgrade the Magento version from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 for enterprise edition.

When running di:compile throws following error.

```
Error: Interface "Magento\InventoryApi\Model\SourceValidatorInterface" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup/Model/Source/Validator/PhoneValidator.php on line 19
```

While checking, found that the following modules are not installed during composer install.

```
 "magento/inventory-composer-installer": "^1.2.0",
 "magento/module-inventory": "1.2.3",
 "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "1.2.3",
 "magento/module-inventory-advanced-checkout": "1.2.2",
 "magento/module-inventory-api": "1.2.3"
```

I tried to install the above modules like

```
composer require magento/module-inventory
```

But Composer shows nothing to install, but the module folder is not present.
Please help.